# Trying to find flux through «stream pipe»

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I'm trying to find the flux of the vector field $$\textbf{v}(x,y)=x^{2}\textbf{i}-2xy\textbf{j}$$ through the «stream pipe»* given by the lines $y=0$ and $y=\frac{1}{x^{2}}$, as shown in [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gmDb.png).

My first thought was to parameterize the lines. However, the parametrization $\textbf{r}(t)=t\textbf{i}+1/t^{2}\textbf{j}$ for $-\infty<t<\infty$ of the blue line is undefined at zero, so the parametrization would not be everywhere defined, and to me that looks like a problem.

I tried using Gauss', but I don't see how to define the volume over which to integrate.

Comment: The flux of a vector field $\textbf{v}$ through a surface $S$ is defined as $C=\iint_{S}\textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{n}\,dS$, where $\textbf{n}$ is the normal vector to the surface $S$. A similar definition holds for the flux through a line, then it is defined as a line integral.

Comment: What surface is there? The area enclosed by the two curves? (The curves themselves are 1-dimensional, hence certainly not a surface.) And are we talking about the normal in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$? (I don't think the answer to the last question matters for the final solution to the problem, per se, but more with regards with how we interpret the problem and thus the choice of method employed to find a solution.)

Comment: Flux in 2D as in http://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/line-integrals-in-vector-fields-articles/a/flux-in-two-dimensions?

Comment: @William That is exactly what I don't understand. The problem does not state if it should be a line integral or a surface integral or indeed anything else than that the flux is «through the stream pipe». I have not been able to find anything on how to solve a problem like this.

Comment: I'm sorry, then I don't think I have any idea either -- the problem does not seem like it is well-phrased, I could be wrong. I tried editing the question to make it more compact so it gets bumped to the front page again.